# How do I place coins on the ground?

Tags: terraria

The changelog for 1.2.4 indicates you can now place coins in the world. I can't figure out how. Do I need to craft them into a pile? Just place them in my hotbar and click? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coins can be placed by selecting them from the inventory, then clicking on the tile you want the coin to be placed on with the coins in hand to place them.

- Coins have to be placed on top of something and cannot float in midair (sand-like behaviour).
- Only 1 coin can be placed per tile.
- Coins can be mined back with the appropriate tool (pickaxe or drill).